# how to make search box in boostrap SB Admin 2

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

i want make select box and i use sb admin 2. when i write code and running my program, it did not work. please help me.
my view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.17/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

 <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="id_obat" name="id_obat" data-live-search="true">
                 <?php 
                 foreach ($id_obat as $data2) {
                  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $data2->id_obat ?>"  <?php if (@$id_obat==$data2->id_obat) echo 'selected' ?>> <?php echo $data2->nama_obat." - ".$data2->satuan;?> 
                      </option>&nbsp;
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/bootstrap-select.js')?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add class="form-control selectpicker mySelect"

and put this js below *bootstrap-select.js*

```
$('.mySelect').selectpicker();
```

hope this help